# Unable to do word-break: break-word css for Chinese and Japanese languages

Tags: css

I have to apply the following CSS property on an HTML label
word-break: break-word
It is working fine in case of roman scripts such as English, German and French, but it's failing in languages such as Chinese, Japanese and Korean
Is there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In HTML and CSS, how do I make japanese text break lines correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249409/in-html-and-css-how-do-i-make-japanese-text-break-lines-correctly)

Comment: @emix- no. I tried line-break as well, doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

English words are separated with spaces, Japanese and Chinese words are not, so you are not able to do what you want with only css

Comment: If I place two Chinese sentences with space in between, break-word still doesn't seem to identify the space token.

Comment: No that wouldn't work either but if you know where each sentence starts and ends, you could put them in separated spans or paragraphs

Comment: The data is coming from an API that I don't have any control over. Can't happen. So what about Japanese, Chinese or other Asian websites? Do none of them break words?